# Sorting array C program

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I need to make a program which sorts out a given array in such a way that the numbers with the same digits will be in front. The order must remain the same. It would be a big problem but I'm not allowed to use any addiodional arrays, functions etc. I really don't know how to sort out the numbers so that the order remains the same. And also the array is max 100 elements.

Example:

Input:
1 22 43 444 51 16 7 8888 90 11

Output:
1,22,444,7,8888,11,43,51,16,90.

I've written this so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a = 0, i = 0, niz[100], temp, N, j, logika, cifra1, cifra2, brojac = 0, brojac2 = 1;
    printf("Unesite brojeve: \n");
    do {
        scanf("%d", &niz[i]);
        if (niz[i] == -1) {
            i--;
            break;
        }
        i++;
    } while (i < 100);

    N = i;

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        a = niz[i];
        logika = 1;
        cifra1 = a % 10;
        cifra2 = niz[i] / 10;


        while (cifra2) {
            if (cifra2 % 10 != cifra1) {
                logika = 0;
                break;
            }
            cifra2 = cifra2 / 10;
        }

        if (a / 10 == 0) logika = 1;

        if (logika == 1) {
            niz[brojac++] = niz[i];
        }
        if (logika == 0) {
            niz[i] = temp;
            niz[N - 1] = niz[i];
            niz[N - i] = temp;
        }
    }

    printf("Nakon preslaganja niz glasi: \n");
    for (i = 0; i <= N; i++) {
        if (i < N)
            printf("%d,", niz[i]);
        else {
            printf("%d.", niz[i]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: probably you mean putting the sorted order into a new array while keeping the original array untouched? otherwise it doesn't make sense

Comment: I mean to replace the elements of the given array to make the repdigits first.

Comment: Someone asked this question [a week ago](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53321864/15168).  Though they didn't get an actual answer — I've not written one up yet because my code uses one of the quadratic sorts.  Using a stable sort (bubble, insert, merge) and appropriate predicate functions to test whether the numbers both have all digits the same or not allows the sort to be done.  Not using any (user-defined) functions is too painful to even think about — I decline point blank to have anything to do with such nonsense.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler *I decline point blank to have anything to do with such nonsense.* – I don't have that much dignity :/

Comment: @Swordfish: One advantage antiquity and decrepitude is that I can make such decisions on the fly without significant risk to my university career (which almost certainly ended longer ago than the OP has been alive).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler *antiquity and decrepitude* – lol

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum { MAX_NUMBERS = 100 };

int main(void)
{
    int numbers[MAX_NUMBERS];
    int numbers_count = 0;

    int input;
    puts("Please enter your numbers, end input with -1:");
    while (numbers_count < MAX_NUMBERS && scanf(" %d", &input) == 1 && input != -1)
        numbers[numbers_count++] = input;

    int current_insertion_point = 0;  // where to insert
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers_count; ++i) {
        int all_digits_the_same = 1;

        // check if number only contains one probably repeated digit:
        int current_number = numbers[i];
        int last_digit = -1;
        while (current_number && all_digits_the_same) {
            int current_digit = current_number % 10;
            current_number /= 10;
            if (last_digit != -1 && current_digit != last_digit)
                all_digits_the_same = 0;
            last_digit = current_digit;
        }

        // insert the number:
        if (all_digits_the_same) {
            int temp = numbers[i];

            // nove the range current_insertion_point ... i to the right
            for (int k = i; k > current_insertion_point; --k)
                numbers[k] = numbers[k - 1];

            // so there is space to insert the number previously numbers[i]
            numbers[current_insertion_point++] = temp;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers_count; ++i)
        printf("%d ", numbers[i]);
    putchar('\n');
}
```

#### Output:

```
Please enter your numbers, end input with -1:
1 22 43 444 51 16 7 8888 90 11 -1
1 22 444 7 8888 11 43 51 16 90
```

Answer (score -1):

I have done selection sort.It's not giving output as you expecting exactly.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int x;
    cout<<"Enter Size Of Array";
    cin>>x;
    const int SIZE=x;
    int a[SIZE];
    int copy[SIZE];
    cout<<"Enter "<<SIZE<<" Value";
    for(int i=0;i<SIZE;i++){
        cin>>a[i];
    }
    for(int i=0;i<SIZE;i++){
        copy[i]=a[i];
    }

    for(int i=0;i<SIZE;i++){
        int n=a[i];
        int temp;
        int rem=n%10;
        bool isAllDigitSame=false;
        while(n!=0){
            if(rem==n%10){
                isAllDigitSame=true;
            }
            else{
                isAllDigitSame=false;
                break;
            }
            n=n/10;
        }

        if(isAllDigitSame){
            temp=a[i];
            a[i] = a[i]%10;
        }
    }

    cout<<"A="<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<SIZE;i++){
        cout<<a[i]<<endl;
    }
    cout<<endl;

    for(int i=0;i<SIZE;i++){
        int min=i;

        for(int j=i;j<SIZE;j++){
            if(a[j]<a[min]){
                min=j;
            }
        }
         int temp;
        temp=copy[i];
        copy[i]=copy[min];
        copy[min]=temp;
        temp=a[i];
        a[i]=a[min];
        a[min]=temp;
    }
    cout<<"Copy="<<endl;

    for(int i=0;i<SIZE;i++){
        cout<<copy[i]<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It is sorting other element also.

```
Input :1 22 43 444 51 16 7 8888 90 11
Output: 1 11 22 444 7 8888 16 43 51 90
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Answer] pages soon.  You have written C++ code as an answer to a question tagged for C only.  This is not helpful as your code certainly won't compile with a pure C compiler.  Additionally, as you yourself admit, the output from your code isn't what the OP wants.  Within the 'same digits' numbers, the output sequence must be the same as in the input sequence, and within the 'different digits' numbers, the output sequence must also be the same as the input sequence.  Your output moves `11` before `22`, `444`, `7` and `8888` — oops!

Comment: I recommend deleting this answer until you can fix the issues — use C library functions and headers rather than C++, and make the algorithm work correctly.  (It can be done!)